# How to read an array of integers from an element to get values from it?

Tags: javascript, html

I make a code , that randomly display an 6-item array in a div.
i want to read the array and pass it to function to calculate the mean of it?

HTML

what i must do , how can i store the data of div(id="numbers" ) 
and push it in array ?

```
 <pre>

  <div >
  <form  action="" method="post" name="meanForm"  onsubmit='return false'            id="formmine">

<table width="100%" border="0" 
<tr>
 <td colspan="3" style="background-color:#06F ;color:#FFF">Answer this   problem</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td style="color:green; font-size:20px">What is the mean of these numbers   </td>
<td colspan="2" ><div id="numbers"></div>
</td>
      </tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
 <tr id="answerANDpic">
   <td height="62" colspan="3"  align="center" > <input name="" type="text"      size="15" maxlength="100" height="50" style=" border: solid #0C0 ; border-width:thin"  id="answer"   onkeydown="searchm(this)"/> </td>
     </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3"  ><div id ="explain" ></div></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td><input name="" type="button" id="newEx" style="background-color:green  ; color:white"  align ="left" value="New Problem" class="send_feed"  onclick="randomArray(6,0,99)" /></td>
    <td><input name="" type="button"  id="solution" style="background-color:#606 ; color:#FFF  " align="left" class="send_feed" value="Solution"  onclick="solution()"/></td>
   </tr>
  </table>



 </form>
   </div>
```

in JS

```
       var myNumArray = randomArray(6,0,99);

      function random_number(min,max) {
      return (Math.round((max-min) * Math.random() + min));
}

function randomArray(num_elements,min,max) {
   var nums = new Array;

   for (var element=0; element<num_elements; element++) {
      nums[element] = random_number(min,max);
    }

   document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML=nums;
    calcMean(nums);
 }




 function calcMean(nums) {
    var num=0;
    for (var i=0;i<nums.length;i++) {
        num += parseFloat( nums[i], 6 );
    }
     var divide=num/nums.length;
    var mean=(parseInt(divide,10));
   var maxi = Math.max.apply(Math,nums);
    var mini = Math.min.apply(Math,nums);

     return mean,maxi,mini;
     }

   function searchm(ele) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
       // alert(ele.value); // i get the value and put it on alert        

       var inans= ele.value;
        return inans;
      }
      }


        function soltuion(){
        //read array saved in div id="numbers"
          // call calcMean()

              //get the mean and max min values 
              }
```

Comment: Add complete code, javascript and HTML

Comment: Can you not read the array directly from the function that created it, rather than placing it in the div, then reading it from the div again?

Comment: Provide us some of your code. make a fiddle and share.

Comment: function calcMean(nums){
var num=0;
    for (var i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
   num += parseFloat( nums[i], 6 )}
    var divide=num/nums.length;
 
  mean=(parseInt(divide,10));
  var maxi = Math.max.apply(Math,nums);
           var mini = Math.min.apply(Math,nums);
return [mean,mini,maxi];

}

Comment: You should add it to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: well , i am new here

Answer (score 0):

See comments in code below. Your code is not far off working.

```
function calcMean(nums){
  var num=0;
  for (var i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
    // parseFloat only has one argument
    // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat
    num += parseFloat( nums[i])

    // If the numbers in the nums array
    // are already floats, you don't need parseFloat
    // So maybe you can do... ?
    // num += nums[i]
  }

  // The line below might divide by zero, so check
  if (nums.length == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  var divide=num/nums.length;

  // No need to reparse a number.
  mean=divide

  // This code suggests that nums is already filled with numbers
  // See comment in for-loop above
  var maxi = Math.max.apply(Math,nums);
  var mini = Math.min.apply(Math,nums);

  // This returns all 3 numbers
  return [mean,mini,maxi];

  // If you want just the mean,
  // return mean;
}
```

Comment: this is a part of my program , i didnt write all the program here , but the problem is how to read the saved array in element of html and passing it to calcMean()
also , what is the type of the value of an element of html?
should i store the value in array?

Comment: Update your question in this way, include the HTML you are talking about